# Hive - How to query a unix timestamp to identify yesterday's values?

Tags: hive

I have the following problem to solve. I have a hive table, that store events, and each event timestamp is stored as unix timestamp (e.g. 1484336244). 
Every day I want to run a query that fetches yesterdays events. 
How could I form this query in Hive? 
So for example, today is the 9th February, I want to get only the events that occurred on the 8th February.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract one day from `current_date` and compare it with the column converted to `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

```
date_add(current_date,-1) = from_unixtime(colName,'yyyy-MM-dd')
```